# No route matches [POST] within two simple form partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two partials that route to the same controller and same model. In both of these partials I am submitting a new form, which I am intending on using the create method in my controller.

My first partial is just simply titled, `_form.html.haml`.
My second partial is where I've been having a problem.  this partial is called `_case_study_form.html.haml`.

Both of these forms have the same information within them, but the problem that i'm having is that on my second partial, when I hit submit I wind up with `No route matches [POST] "/case_study"` Yet the problem that I am truly having is that I don't know exactly what I am missing within the routes.  If anyone could take a quick look at this, I would greatly appreciate it!

When I type in `rake routes` I get

```
    form_submissions GET    /form_submissions(.:format)          form_submissions#index
                     POST   /form_submissions(.:format)          form_submissions#create
 new_form_submission GET    /form_submissions/new(.:format)      form_submissions#new
edit_form_submission GET    /form_submissions/:id/edit(.:format) form_submissions#edit
     form_submission GET    /form_submissions/:id(.:format)      form_submissions#show
                     PATCH  /form_submissions/:id(.:format)      form_submissions#update
                     PUT    /form_submissions/:id(.:format)      form_submissions#update
                     DELETE /form_submissions/:id(.:format)      form_submissions#destroy
             contact GET    /contact(.:format)                   form_submissions#new
          case_study GET    /case_study(.:format)                form_submissions#case_study
```

With my `routes.rb` file looking like

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :form_submissions
  root 'home#index'
  get '/contact' => 'form_submissions#new'
  get '/case_study' => 'form_submissions#case_study'
```

In both of my partials my code they are quite similar with mostly styling differences, but.

my `_form.html.haml` is

```
= simple_form_for @form_submission do |f|
(lots of code here in the body)
= f.submit 'Submit', class: "btn btn-default"
```

My second partial, `_case_study_form.html.haml` is

```
= simple_form_for @form_submission, url: case_study_path do |f|
(lots of code here in the body with different styling)
= f.submit 'Submit', class: "btn btn-default"
```

and my controller looks like

```
class FormSubmissionsController < ApplicationController
  invisible_captcha only: [:create], on_spam: :handle_spam

  def new
    @form_submission ||= FormSubmission.new
  end

  def create
    @form_submission = FormSubmission.new(form_submission_params)

    if @form_submission.save
      redirect_to thank_you_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def case_study
    @form_submission ||= FormSubmission.new

    if @form_submission.save
      redirect_to thank_you_path
    else
      render :case_study
    end
  end

  private

  def handle_spam
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def form_submission_params
    params.require(:form_submission).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :organization, :email, :phone, :recognition, :inquiry, :form_submission)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but I can at least answer the question.  Your form is attempting to POST to the url you provided, `case_study_path`, but in your `routes.rb` you specify this as a GET route.  Hence, no route found.

To make the route found, you need to define it in `routes.rb`.

That said, it seems like you would intend to use the same save handler as the regular form; in that case, you don't need to override the URL in the form itself, just let it use the create method that it would have used anyway.  But, if you don't, then you need to define it in `routes.rb` as a POST route, i.e.

```
post '/case_study/create' => 'form_submissions#create', as: 'submit_case_study'
```

Comment: Hi @GoGoCarl, thank you so much for your response and taking a look at the question.  I ultimately would like to use the create method within the controller. I did not want to essentially copy what was in the create method in the case_study method.  So, ultimately, i'm wondering, would you happen to know how to use the create method within this partial?

Comment: Ok, that's kind of what I figured.  If you want to use the form submission create method for the case study form, then just remove the `url: case_study_path` from the partial.  Because you are providing the object `form_submission`, it will know how to generate the POST url.  In the `case_study` method in your controller, you can remove all that save stuff.

Comment: You are the best!  Learned a lot this afternoon thank you!